# Why my regular notifications are stopped after my phone is getting off?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I wrote an app and I set an alarm manager which set to send a notification every 3 hours. Assume my notification has to be send at 11:10 and my phone is getting off at 11:00. So, I will not receive any notification. When my phone is turned on, I will receive the next notification at 2:10, so everything is working correctly.

Although, it was observed that I will not receive any notification after my phone is getting off for two round of notification. Do you have any suggestion?

The code is provided:

```
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(this, NotifyBroadcast.class);
                      PendingIntent pintentAlarm = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                      AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                      // Start every 30 seconds
                      mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis(), 300, pintentAlarm);


// NotifyBroadcast:


public  class NotifyBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub




    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);


            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    context,
                    0,
                    resultIntent,
                    0
                ); 



            Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Let me know what is your emotion buddy!", System.currentTimeMillis());
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            notification.sound = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/notification/notification.mp3");
            //notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "emotion interface", "Let me know what is your emotion buddy!", resultPendingIntent);



            int mId = 001;
            // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
            mNotificationManager.notify(mId, notification); 
          //  mNotificationManager.notify(mId,mBuilder.build());

            // mNotificationManager.cancel(mId);

}
```

}

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is?  Do you mean that in your example your phone not only missed the 11:10 notification, but also the 2:10 notification, and you want to know why?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand following part very well :

> `I will not receive any notification after my phone is getting off for two round of notification` .

Just check that you are relaunching your service after reboot. For that you need to add a receiver that launches your Service again after the reboot. You need to handle that on  `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` intent broadcast. Some of the questions that might help you are:

[Android: make notification persist across phone reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071598/android-make-notification-persist-across-phone-reboot)

[android notification after reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461208/android-notification-after-reboot)

[Android: why did the Alarm notification stop after system reboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056416/android-why-did-the-alarm-notification-stop-after-system-reboot)

Hope this helps in some way.